# Use I18n with Rails ActiveRecord Vaildation Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, internationalization

I am building an app, using I18n for different languages display. In this moment, the validation message shown in this way.

**en**

```
USERNAME CAN'T BE BLANK
```

**zh-CN**

```
USERNAME 不能为空字符
```

I would like to translate the attribute *USERNAME* to some other string. So I followed the instruction in [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) and added the following lines in my locale files.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        username: "User Name"


zh-CN:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        username: "用户名"
```

When I run the human_attribute_name command, it can be translated.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > User.human_attribute_name("username")
 => "Username"
```

But in the validation message, it just capitalized all the characters of attribute name.

```
CURRENT_PASSWORD 不能为空字符
```

Did I missed anything? How can I fix it?

Thank all. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models: 
        user:
          attributes:
            username: "User Name"
```

Comment: Thanks @chrispanda. I tried your method, but the problem isn't fixed. I updated the question. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Thanks buddy. I just found that I used a helper method which override the validation message setting. I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. I added a custom helper to handle the validation message. The I18n translation in question is correct. I can use human_attribute_name to translate the arribute.